# Issue with if statments(null) and changing innerHtml property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, conditional-statements

I am messing around trying to learn more JS. I wanted to do a simple if/else statement to get the text of a paragraph to change if a string is empty or not.

The issue is that the statement doesn't execute properly for both cases. It actually remains the same text that is shown initially.

Here's my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Time to practice: Adding elements with Javascript</title>
</head>
<body>

  <main>
    
  </main>

  <script>
    document.body.style.cssText = 'height: 100vw; width: 100vw';
    var main = document.body.children[0].style.cssText = 'background-color: white; height: 100vw; width: 100vw';
    var style = document.createElement('style');
    style.innerHTML = `
      #mainP {
        font-size: 100px;
      }`
    ;
    document.head.appendChild(style);

    var name = prompt("What's your name?");
    var newP = document.createElement('p');
    newP.setAttribute('id', 'mainP');
    document.body.children[0].appendChild(newP);
    
    console.log(name);

    if (name === null) {
      document.getElementById('mainP').innerHTML = "I didn't even want to know your name ";
    } else {
      document.getElementById('mainP').innerHTML = 'Hello ' + name + '.' + ' Hope you are having an awesome day!';
    }
  </script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Drew you state that you want to do x if name is empty string but you're checking against null. To check an empty string you could change null to "".

Comment: Here a simple solution is to use the loose comparison, that would cover the both cases, the empty string and `null`, but won't fail with any actual value.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions guys. Unfortunately, none of them worked in my case. I really don't know what the issue is. Logically it should work but it doesn't.

Comment: I've solved it in the end with help from one of my friends. I don't know why, but in order for it to work as intended I had to do if(name == 'null'). We tried to figure out why the script would run only with null as a string but we didn't come to any conclusions.

Answer (score 0):

In the conditional statement if(name == null), null was transformed for some reason to string. If you change the statement to if(name == 'null') it works as intended.